# How to run php with Eclipse and XAMPP?

Tags: apache2, php, eclipse, lamp, xampp

I'm using eclipse kepler on ubuntu 14.04, and I want to know how do I run a php project? I already installed the plugin in eclipse for php and when command run the project, the page does not load in the browser. I know this is why I have to save the php pages in the xampp directory: / opt / lampp / htdocs.
My PHP files are in the eclipse workspace in my home folder, how can I run from the workspace if that is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

give permission to create inside of htdocs

```
sudo chmod 777 -R /opt/lampp/htdocs
```

or more details:

https://superuser.com/questions/268987/cant-create-any-folder-in-htdocs-on-ubuntu